# Redux with Angular -?

Tags: angular, redux, frontend

I want to use Redux  pattern with Angular (^6.1.6), reason being I am working with an application in which I have complex component and module interactions, where component view is updated via web-socket and this update needs to be reflected at other components like overview component of the application.

What would be good to use `angular-redux/store` or `ngrx/store`.
Or is there any other way to achieve the same in angular.

Answer (score 1):

Actively using `ngrx/store`, with `ngrx/effects` and other libs in most of my angular 5 or 6 apps. It's straightforward. Was able to achieve unidirectional data flow as meant, so I commend `ngrx`. Have not used `angular-redux/store`.